# How to get information from xml file's child node with PowerShell

Tags: xml, powershell

I have a xml file with nodes like this:

```
<xml>
  <n n="GUID1" t="folder">   
    <a n="name" v="smthng1" />
    <a n="path" v="/abc/QWERTY/ghi" /> 
  </n>
  <n n="GUID2" t="folder">   
    <a n="name" v="smthng2" />
    <a n="path" v="/abc/def/ghi" />
  </n>
</xml>
```

I need to get GUIDs from the first node, but only if path node does not have "QWERTY" in it.

I'm getting all guids with this script:

```
$Files_xml = [System.Xml.XmlDocument](Get-Content "C:\Files.xml")
[System.Collections.ArrayList] $Files_links = @()
select-xml -xpath "//n[@t='folder']" -xml $Files_xml |  foreach {$Files_links += $_.Node.Attributes.GetNamedItem('n').Value}
```

And I'm kinda lost how to select only needed ones

Comment: You cannot type cast a string to an XmlDocument. That cannot be your actual code.

Comment: @PalleDue You absolutely can.  Literally copy/paste their example. It works.

Comment: I don't really understand what you mean, but that code is working, you can try it yourself:

Comment: `[xml]$Files_xml = @"
    <xml>
        <n n="GUID123" t="folder">   
            <a n="name" v="smthng1" />
            <a n="path" v="/abc/QWERTY/ghi" />
        </n>
        <n n="GUID321" t="folder">   
            <a n="name" v="smthng2" />
            <a n="path" v="/abc/def/ghi" />
        </n>
    </xml>
"@

$Files_links = new-object System.Collections.ArrayList
select-xml -xpath "//n[@t='folder']" -xml $Files_xml |  foreach {$Files_links += $_.Node.Attributes.GetNamedItem('n').Value}
$Files_links`

Comment: Sorry, you guys are right. I did copy the code, but was fooled by the fact that there is no root tag in the xml.

Comment: I suppose `[xml] (Get-Content ...)` is shorthand for `[System.Xml.XmlDocument] (Get-Content ...)` then. I normally use just `[xml]`.

Comment: @PalleDue `[xml]` is a type accelerator for the `XmlDocument` type.

Comment: @TheIncorrigle: Type accelerator, OK, thanks, I learned a new concept.

Comment: @PalleDue Try this: `$type =  [psobject].Assembly.GetType('System.Management.Automation.TypeAccelerators'); $type::Get`.  You can even add your own with the `::Add()` method.

Answer (score 0):

You need to filter lower:

```
$xml = [xml](Get-Content -Path C:\Files.xml)
$links = $xml.SelectNodes(
    '//n[@t="folder" and a[@n="path" and not(contains(@v, "QWERTY"))]]/@n'
)
```

If you prefer using `Select-Xml`:

```
$selectXmlParams = @{
    'XPath'       = '//n[@t="folder" and a[@n="path" and not(contains(@v, "QWERTY"))]]/@n'
    'LiteralPath' = 'C:\Files.xml'
}
$links = Select-Xml @selectXmlParams
```

Comment: It does not really work...
In result, $link contains only 'n' and not guids

Comment: @Eric what version of PowerShell are you on? This worked fine when I tested it.

Comment: version 5.0     
Major  Minor  Build  Revision
-----  -----  -----  --------
5      0      10240  17443

Comment: If you remove `.ToString()`, do you see your GUIDs in the object? @Eric

Comment: Yes! Thank you =) But i needed actually other guid, without QWERTY, but I think there must be opposite of contains method

Comment: That works!
Your second option showing me in `$links` that string: 
`n    C:\Files.xml //n[@t="folder" and a[@n="path" and not(contains(@v, "QWERTY"))]]/@n`

Comment: @Eric Great, if my answer solved your question, please mark it as such ✔